# ejs code to display flash message in angular for ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, passport.js, csrf, ejs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get ejs code into angular, because I am using a csrf token, message flash and need to put in the ionic to display the flash message. The ejs in the html shows the text

```
<% if (hasErrors) {%>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<% messages.forEach(function(message){ %>
<p><%= message %></p>
 <% });%>
</div>
<% }%>
```

how do i convert to to angular get just the data....

This is the backend im using express

```
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();
   var User = require('../models/User.js');
   var csrf = require('csurf');
   var passport = require('passport');

   var csrfProtection = csrf();
   router.use(csrfProtection);



  /* GET signup page. */
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('signup', { title: 'Sign Up'});
   });

   /*GET create account page.*/
     router.get('/register', function(req, res, next){
   var messages = req.flash('error');
   res.render('register', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: messages, hasErrors:messages.length >0 });
   });
  /*POST register saves email then go to questions*/
   router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local.register',{
   successRedirect: 'questions',
   failureRedirect: '/',
   failureFlash: true
  }));


  router.get('questions', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('questions'); 
  })
```

Register.html (I know I have to put something around the ejs code)

```
<div id="createaccount">
<a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-light" a href="#/signup"></a>
<h1 class="hidden">Creating Account</h1>
<img src="../img/logo.png" alt=logo id="logo">
<div id="footer">
<div class="imageHolder">
<img src="../img/email.png" alt=mail id="emailIcon">
<img src="../img/key.png" alt="key" id="keyIcon">
</div>

<% if (hasErrors) {%>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<% messages.forEach(function(message){ %>
   <p><%= message %></p>
 <% });%>
 </div>
 <% }%>

 <div class="list list-inset" id="form">
 <form action="register" method="post">
 <label class="item item-input"> 
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
 </label>
 <label class="item item-input" id="passform"> 
 <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
 </label>
 <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken%>"/>

 <div> 
 <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" a href="#/questions" button class="button" id="submitbutton"></a>
 </div>
 </div>

  </form>
  </div>

  </div>
```

app.js this is what i have so far and i know i have to put something here

```
  var HCapp = angular.module('HCapp',['ionic','ui.router']);

  HCapp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('signup', {  
  url: '/signup', 
  templateUrl: 'views/signup.html'
  })

  .state('register',{
  url:'/register',
  templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
   })

  .state('sign-in', {
  url:'/sign-in',
  templateUrl: 'views/sign-in.html'
   })

    .state('questions',{
    url:'/questions',
   templateUrl: 'views/questions.html'
 })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('signup');
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

ejs requires a templating engine to be run which won't exist in ionic since there is no node runtime or templating engine. If you want this support you'll need to add a custom cordova plugin.